# How do I install libusbx library

Tags: bash, 13.10, android

I am trying to run [flashtool](https://unrestrict.li/flashtool) (flashing utility for android phones) in ubuntu. Already setup java and appropriate environment

On execution the following error comes up

```
rajeswar@WebE-PCl:~$ FlashTool/FlashTool
Not running as root but Sony/SonyEriccson Vendor ID found on your udev rules
if Flashing didn't work well, run flashtool as root
libusb.LibUsbException: Libusb not found. Minimum libusb version is 1.0.15. It can be downloaded on http://www.libusbx.org
    at libusb.UsbSystem.initSystem(UsbSystem.java:28)
    at libusb.UsbSystem.<init>(UsbSystem.java:15)
    at linuxlib.JUsb.init(JUsb.java:21)
    at gui.Main.initLinuxUsb(Main.java:47)
    at gui.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

So I downloaded the latest version from http://libusbx.org/, after extraction executed

`./configure && sudo make && sudo make install && sudo ldconfig`.

It executed successfully & installed to `/usr/local/lib/`.. But the error keeps coming..

This is output of `sudo ldconfig -vp | grep usb`

```
libusbmuxd.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libusbmuxd.so.2
libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
libusb-1.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so
libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
libgusb.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgusb.so.2
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Below is content of flashtool launcher script

```
#!/bin/sh

export BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
export system64=$(uname -m)
export OS=$(uname -s)

cd $BASEDIR

if test "$OS" = "Linux"
then
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/adb.linux
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/fastboot.linux
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/unyaffs.linux
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/bin2elf
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/bin2sin
    if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
    then
    export HASRULES="false"
    if test -d /etc/udev/rules.d
    then
            if grep -rl "0fce" /etc/udev/rules.d >/dev/null
            then
            export HASRULES="true"
        fi
    fi
    if test "$HASRULES" = "true"
    then
            echo "Not running as root but Sony/SonyEriccson Vendor ID found on your udev rules"
            echo "if Flashing didn't work well, run flashtool as root"
        else
            echo "Not running as root and there is no Sony/SonyEriccson Vendor ID on your udev rules"   
            echo "The user must be granted access to adb/flashmode/fastboot"
            echo "If you are unsure what to do, run flashtool as root"
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Running as root."
    fi
    if test -z "${JAVA_HOME}"
    then
        if test "${system64}" = "x86_64"
        then
             export JAVA_HOME=./x10flasher_lib/linjre64

        else
             export JAVA_HOME=./x10flasher_lib/linjre32

        fi
        echo "JAVA_HOME not set. Using default value : ${JAVA_HOME}"
    fi
    if test -e ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
    then
         export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32
         export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
         ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32/libusbx-1.0.so
         ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64/libusbx-1.0.so

         ISJAVA6=$($JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1|grep version|grep 1.6|wc -l)
         ISJAVA7=$($JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1|grep version|grep 1.7|wc -l)
         ISJAVA64=$($JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1|grep 64-Bit|wc -l)
     if test $ISJAVA6 -gt 0 -o $ISJAVA7 -gt 0
     then
            if test $ISJAVA64 -gt 0
            then
                ln -sf swt64.jar ./x10flasher_lib/swtlin/swt.jar
            else
                ln -sf swt32.jar ./x10flasher_lib/swtlin/swt.jar
            fi
            $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -jar x10flasher.jar
     else
        echo "Java version must be 1.6 or 1.7"
     fi
    else
         echo "No Java in specified path in JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}"
         echo "Set the variable to a valid Java installation"
    fi
else
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/adb.mac
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/fastboot.mac
    chmod 755 ./x10flasher_lib/unyaffs.mac
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/mac/lib64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/mac/lib32:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
    ln -sf libusbx-1.0.0.dylib ./x10flasher_lib/mac/lib64/libusbx-1.0.dylib
    ln -sf libusbx-1.0.0.dylib ./x10flasher_lib/mac/lib32/libusbx-1.0.dylib
    ISJAVA6=$(java -version 2>&1|grep version|grep 1.6|wc -l)
    ISJAVA7=$(java -version 2>&1|grep version|grep 1.7|wc -l)
    ISJAVA64=$(java -version 2>&1|grep 64-Bit|wc -l)
    if test $ISJAVA64 -gt 0
    then
        ln -sf swt64.jar ./x10flasher_lib/swtmac/swt.jar
    else
        ln -sf swt32.jar ./x10flasher_lib/swtmac/swt.jar
    fi
    if test $ISJAVA6 -gt 0 -o $ISJAVA7  -gt 0
    then
        java -XstartOnFirstThread -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -jar x10flasher.jar
    else
        echo "Java version must be 1.6 or 1.7"
    fi
fi
```

I think the problem lies in these lines

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32/libusbx-1.0.so
ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64/libusbx-1.0.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution. Adding it for any future reference

Copy `/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0` to `FlashTool/x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64` and `FlashTool/x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32`.

Search the following lines in Flashtool script

```
ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32/libusbx-1.0.so
ln -sf libusbx-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64/libusbx-1.0.so
```

Change them to

```
ln -sf libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib32/libusbx-1.0.so
ln -sf libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0 ./x10flasher_lib/linux/lib64/libusbx-1.0.so
```

Now run the flashtool, you will be good to go.

---

Note:

Who are getting `JAVA_HOME NOT SET` error before it, do the following

This will set variable for all user

`sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/java.sh`

paste if you installed oracle jdk, change accordingly if you are using open jdk

```
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Then in terminal run:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/java.sh
source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477524/714518)

---

If you get `cannot open shared library libncurses.so.5` after flashtool GUI comes up,
install 32bit version of the library

`sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17617448/714518)